# Finding prominent frequency from FFT

Tags: python, scipy, fft, frequency-analysis, audio-analysis

I've set up a python audio stream and fft using bits of code for an audio spectrum analyser https://github.com/markjay4k/Audio-Spectrum-Analyzer-in-Python/blob/master/audio%20spectrum_pt2_spectrum_analyzer.ipynb (I removed all the plotting code), I want to find the most prominent frequency from my fft.

```py
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import struct
from scipy.fftpack import fft
import sys
import time


class AudioStream(object):
    def __init__(self):

        # stream constants
        self.CHUNK = 1024 * 2
        self.FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
        self.CHANNELS = 1
        self.RATE = 44100
        self.pause = False

        # stream object
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.p.open(
            format=self.FORMAT,
            channels=self.CHANNELS,
            rate=self.RATE,
            input=True,
            output=True,
            frames_per_buffer=self.CHUNK,
        )
        self.start_recording()

    def start_recording(self):

        print('stream started')

        while True:
            #Get data from stream and unpack to data_int
            data = self.stream.read(self.CHUNK)
            data_int = struct.unpack(str(2 * self.CHUNK) + 'B', data)

            # compute FFT
            yf = fft(data_int)

            # find the most prominent frequency from this fft


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AudioStream()
```

Below is a screenshot of the output from the non-adapted audio spectrum analyzer on github, showing the value I want to get from the fft (most prominent frequency). In this case, the value is around 1555Hz.

[image: Image of desired value]

Comment: Related to [Find value and bin of fft max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049887/print-highest-peak-value-of-the-frequency-domain-plot)

Comment: here is a crisp concise example of what the FFT means and how to handle its output https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkGsMWi_j4Q

Answer (score 2):

I found some code that does this using the question [Audio Frequencies in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308674/audio-frequencies-in-python), I'll leave it bellow:

```
# compute FFT
fftData=abs(np.fft.rfft(data_int))**2
# find the maximum
which = fftData[1:].argmax() + 1
# use quadratic interpolation around the max
if which != len(fftData)-1:
    y0,y1,y2 = np.log(fftData[which-1:which+2:])
    x1 = (y2 - y0) * .5 / (2 * y1 - y2 - y0)
    # find the frequency and output it
    thefreq = (which+x1)*self.RATE/self.CHUNK
    print(f"The freq is {thefreq} Hz.")
else:
    thefreq = which*self.RATE/self.CHUNK
    print (f"The freq is {thefreq} Hz.")
```

Answer (score 1):

If yf is the result from the fft, then you need to find the maximum value in it, correct?  If it is a numpy array, the amax() function will help you here.  @DarrylG points you in the right direction; [Print highest peak value of the frequency domain plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049887/print-highest-peak-value-of-the-frequency-domain-plot)

Comment: This just returns a load of complex numbers :/

Comment: @Peter  if you aspire to becoming a productive independent software engineer you need to muster up the horns to master knowing how to handle an array of complex numbers

Comment: @ScottStensland Yep, you're right. I don't even know what an fft is. I was trying to build a piano tuner for a friend, but I guess this isn't for me.

Comment: Don't give up!  The FFT part isn't too horrible.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/fourier-transform-for-dummies

Comment: @asylumax Thanks a lot! I'll read this and give it another shot.